# How to get value of option from html select tag using php

Tags: php, html, select, web

```
 <select name=category>
    <option value='1'>Adventure</option>
    <option value='2'>Drama</option>
 </select>
```

I want to have the value of selected option. Like if Adventure is selected I want to store 1 or if drama is selected I want to store 2 . How can I do this using php?
I have to add this data to a database table where I can't enter the name . I have to add their id . id 1 is for adventure, 2 for drama.

Comment: by `$_POST['category']` or `$_GET['category']` as per your form method

Comment: if I use $_POST['category'] or $_GET['category'] I will get selected option text not value. I want value of selected option not the text.

Comment: That's not true, you will get the value, not the text..

Comment: `<select name=category>`  should be like this `<select name="category">`

Comment: @krushiovida HTML would actually accept that as a value too (even without quotes), but you're indeed right that one should quote it. The real problem here is that we're not seeing any `<form>` tags.

Comment: @Qirel yea you are right,  but its good to always be safe to avoid any future deprecation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want something like this

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['category']))
{
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    echo "$category";
}
?>

<form method="post" action="" name="form">  
 <select name="category">
    <option value="1">Adventure</option>
    <option value="2">Drama</option>
 </select>
 <input name="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to wrap it in a form.

```
<form action="myphppage.php" method="POST">
    <select name=category>
        <option value='1'>Adventure</option>
        <option value='2'>Drama</option>
    </select>
</form
```

Then on myphppage.php you can get the value from your select by doing:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['category'])) {
    $category = $_POST['category']; // or $_GET['category'] if your form method was GET
}
?>
```